# Data is sent to the form python script, get a code 200, but dont take a letter (result of work view)

Tags: python, django

I can't send in the form on the website data through the python script. The usual feedback form, which works properly when manually filling, but does not send anything if you send a request script. What to do?

The script sending a request to the site:

```
import requests
import sys

URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
client = requests.session()
client.get(URL)
csrftoken = client.cookies['csrftoken']

login_data = dict(lastname='Игин', name='Anton', middlename='Konst', birthday='2017-04-20', telephone='(896) 097-29-02', csrfmiddlewaretoken=csrftoken, next='form_call/')
r = client.post(URL, data=login_data, headers=dict(Referer=URL))
```

views.py

```
def form_call(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = Call_Form(request.POST)
        name = request.POST.get('name', '')
        lastname = request.POST.get('lastname', '')
        middlename = request.POST.get('middlename', '')
        birthday = request.POST.get('birthday', '')
        telephone = request.POST.get('telephone', '')
        if form.is_valid():
            mail_host = SMTPMail.objects.all()[0] 
            rec_list = RecMail.objects.all()
            recipients= []
            for mail in rec_list:
                recipients.append(mail.mail) #Список получателей
            message = '''
                На сайте вашей структуры NL International появилась новая заявка на звонок! Вот данные, предоставленные новым консультантом:
                ФИО:{0} {1} {2}
                Дата рождения: {3}
                Телефон: {4}'''.format(name,lastname, middlename, birthday, telephone)
            subject= 'Заявка на звонок'
            send_mail(subject, message, mail_host.mail, recipients, fail_silently=False)
            return redirect('/thanks/')
        else:
            return redirect('/error/')
```

Comment: what email backend you use in settings.py

Answer (score 1):

I am already solved my problem. There is my code:

```
import requests
import sys

URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' #address of web page with html form
URL2 = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/form_call/' #address of view processing form data
client = requests.session()
client.get(URL)
csrftoken = client.cookies['csrftoken']

login_data = dict(lastname='Игин', name='Anton', middlename='Konst testim', birthday='2017-01-20', telephone='896-002-00-02', csrfmiddlewaretoken=csrftoken)
r = client.post(URL2, data=login_data)
```